# How do I select the last N elements with XPath?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

I support a web site which generates content XML that is then translated into web pages using XSLT.  I have been asked to create a new stylesheet which will transform the output of the "archive" page into Atom for syndication.  The problem I'm running into is that the archive page contains a rather large number of items — 142 and counting — and the feed should never have more than thirty items.

Currently, the output from the archive page looks something like this:

```
<archive>
    <year>
        <month>
            <day>
            <day>
            ...
        </month>

        ...
    </year>

    ...
</archive>
```

The `year` and `month` tags are used by the HTML transform but are completely irrelevant for an Atom feed.  I had hoped that using the `position()` function with the descendant axis would work (`//day[position()>last()-30]`), but this selects the last 30 days *of each month*, which isn't at all what I need.  :-)

Is there a way to do this with XSLT or XPath?  Having to modify the XML generator to add, say, a `feed="true"` attribute to the last thirty days seems like a pretty nasty kludge.

Comment: So which days do you want? the first 30?

Comment: Sorry, the last 30. The entries are in chronological order, so the most recent are at the end.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

position()/last() returns position/last position within the current context, so when the navigator is positioned in one <month>, position() will return <day> within that month, and last() will return last <day> within that month, but i guess you know that.

Therefore, what you could do is flatten all <day>'s in an array and put in a variable, prior to selecting just like you did before.

```
<xsl:variable name="days" select="//day"/>
<xsl:apply-templates select="$days[position()>last()-30]" />
```

Comment: I think that's pretty clever. Is there a lot of call for that technique?

Comment: Sorry, but i am not sure what you mean by a lot of call? If you mean is it a commonly known technique, i don't think so. Just a creative workaround!!! :)

Comment: Just found out you can do this without creating a variable by not using the `//` shortcut. See my answer.

Answer (score 4):

Browsing through the [XSLT spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath#path-abbrev) today, I found a note which explains why `//` behaves this way:

> `//` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/`. For example, `//para` is short for `/descendant-or-self::node()/child::para` and so will select any `para` element in the document (even a `para` element that is a document element will be selected by `//para` since the document element node is a child of the root node); `div//para` is short for `div/descendant-or-self::node()/child::para` and so will select all `para` descendants of div children.
>
> **NOTE:** The location path `//para[1]` does not mean the same as the location path `/descendant::para[1]`. The latter selects the first descendant `para` element; the former selects all descendant `para` elements that are the first `para` children of their parents.

In other words, when using `//`, the `position()` is calculated along the `child` axis, not the `descendant-or-self` axis.  Specifying `descendant` or `descendant-or-self` allows you to get the first/last *n* nodes as you'd expect:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::day[position()>last()-30]"/>
```