# Combine XPATH predicate with position

Tags: xpath, predicate

I have a collection of div elements that have the class `media-gallery-item`.
I would like to select element number x.

When just selecting all items, I get 5 results

```
$x("//div[@id='content-area']//div[@class='media-gallery-item']")
```

Now I want to be able to select item number 2, but I can't figure out how to combine the two properly:

```
$x("//div[@id='content-area']//div[@class='media-gallery-item'][2]")

$x("//div[@id='content-area']//div[@class='media-gallery-item'
                                   and position() = 2]")
```

I know these don't make a lot of sense since it's not an actual `AND`, but more like: "filter according to this first, then select the 2nd match".
The goal of this is to keep on selecting things (e.g. in the second element, get me the `href` attribute of the `a` element)

Comment: Just the first duplicate found [How do I select the last N elements with XPath?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/458596/how-do-i-select-the-last-n-elements-with-xpath)

Comment: That is not a duplicate. I want a specific position and combine it with another predicate. The other post wants the last n items (no other predicate, not exact position)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Step-by-step answer.

To select elements with a `div[@id='content-area']` ancestor, which are the second children of their respective parents use:

```
//div[@id='content-area']//div[2]
```

To select second (in document order) `div` element with a `div[@id='content-area']` ancestor use:

```
(//div[@id='content-area']//div)[2]
```

**Do note the difference.**

Then, to select elements, which are second children of their respective parents, providing they have a class 'media-gallery-item' use:

```
//div[@id='content-area']//div[2][@class='media-gallery-item']
```

To select elements, which are the second from those children (of their respective parents) that have a class `media-gallery-item`:

```
//div[@id='content-area']//div[@class='media-gallery-item'][2]
```

To select second (in document order) `div` element with a `div[@id='content-area']` ancestor, providing it has `media-gallery-item` class:

```
(//div[@id='content-area']//div)[2][@class='media-gallery-item']
```

To select second (in document order) from all `div` element with a `div[@id='content-area']` ancestor and a `media-gallery-item` class:

```
(//div[@id='content-area']//div)[@class='media-gallery-item'][2]
```

**Spec quotes** as suggested by @Alejandro:

> A predicate filters a node-set with
>   respect to an axis to produce a new
>   node-set. For each node in the
>   node-set to be filtered, the
>   PredicateExpr is evaluated with that
>   node as the context node, with the
>   number of nodes in the node-set as the
>   context size, and with the proximity
>   position of the node in the node-set
>   with respect to the axis as the
>   context position

http://w3.org/TR/xpath/#predicates

> The proximity position of a member of
>   a node-set with respect to an axis is
>   defined to be the position of the node
>   in the node-set ordered in document
>   order if the axis is a forward axis
>   and ordered in reverse document order
>   if the axis is a reverse axis

http://w3.org/TR/xpath/#dt-proximity-position

Bottom line is that the position predicate works with respect to the axis. And you need parenthesis to explicitly declare the priority. Thus not the `child` axis, but the node-set after resolving `descendant-or-self` axis will be considered, when calculating position.

Comment: @Alejandro, familiar quotes now :) I'll add them to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out: parenthesis!

```
(//div[@id='content-area']//div[@class='media-gallery-item'])[2]
```

works

Comment: You can also check my answer for a complete analysis.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your accessing attributes in the wrong way. Try to use

```
/div[@id='content-area' and @class='media-gallery-item'][2]
```