# Is this XPath technique reliable in all situations?

Tags: xpath, nodesets

I am developing an application that accepts user-defined XPath expressions and employs them as part of its runtime operation.

However, I would like to be able to infer some additional data by programmatically manipulating the expression, and I am curious to know whether there are any situations in which this approach might fail.

Given any user-defined XPath expression that returns a node set, is it safe to wrap it in the XPath `count()` function to determine the number of nodes in the set:

```
count(user_defined_expression)
```

Similarly, is it safe to append an array index to the expression to extract one of the nodes in the set:

```
user_defined_expression[1]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well an XPath expression (in XPath 1.0) can yield a node-set or a string or a number or a boolean and doing count(expression) only makes sense on any expression yielding a node-set.

As for adding a positional predicate, I think you might want to use parentheses around your expression i.e. to change `/root/foo/bar` into `(/root/foo/bar)[1]` as that way you select the first `bar` element in the node-set selected by `/root/foo/bar` while without them you would get `/root/foo/bar[1]` which would select the first `bar` child element of any `foo` child element of the `root` element.

Comment: Glad to see that I raise the same possible problems :)

Comment: thanks, that was exactly the kind of unexpected complication that I was trying to avoid.

Comment: I'm glad to come across this comment: I was trying to figure out how to use position()=N or [N] as a way to find the Nth *match* as opposed to the Nth item among its in-context DOM siblings, and somehow I tried everything except parenthesis.

Answer (score 2):

Are you checking that such user-defined expressions always evaluate to node-set?

If yes, first Expr is ok. Datatype will be correct for [`fn:count`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-count)

Second one is a lot trickier, with a lot of situations there predicate will overweight axis, for example. [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961349/combine-xpath-predicate-with-position/4961505#4961505) for a simple analysis. It will be difficult to say, what a user really meant.

Comment: thanks also. Your answer is very close the answer I accepted (and it's a pity I can't accept both), but Martin's approach is likely to cover the scenarios that my app will face.

Answer (score 1):

A more robust approach would be to convert the XPath expression to XQueryX, which is an XML representation of the abstract syntax tree; you can then do XQuery or XSLT transformations on this XML representation, and then convert back to a modified XPath (or XQuery) for evaluation.

However, this will still only give you the syntactic structure of the expression; if you want semantic information, such as the inferred static type of the result, you will probably have to poke inside an XPath process that exposes this information.

Comment: +1 Parsing the expression will bring more information. Little addition: an standard DOM Level 3 XPath implementation also gives the right tools to know **after the evaluation** the result data type among other things (node set length, i.e).